# Executing a specific method from a source class using unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing

Is there an unit testing annotation or feature flag that I can insert in my java source code so that the method will only be triggered when running unit test?

For Example:

```
public class A {        
    @Annotation
    public void fooA() { }

    public void fooB() { }
}
```

My Unit test class:

```
public class TestA {
  ...
}
```

In this scenario, when I run my unit test class TestA, I want to execute **fooA() and fooB()**.

But if I would like to run my prod source code that includes classA, then only function **fooB() will be executed and not fooA()**.

Comment: Not following the reasoning for it. You should not care for the environment this is running in. If tests need some special environment - let them set it up for their own.

Comment: So is this "design for test"?  Is `fooA()` only public so you can call it as part of a test harness?  Essentially it should be a private method but you have to make it public so you can test it.

Comment: Why are you wasting effort testing something which is not even included in  production version of your software?

Comment: Well the reason behind it is because I have different build variants. One of the build variants actually fails with one of the unit tests because that same unit test function trigger some undesired logic, so I wanted to exclude it under a method with a unit test annotation, if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general: don't go there.

Your production code has one responsibility; and one responsibility only: to do its production job. You do not factor in **complex** test-related aspects.

Occasionally, it might be required or helpful to have a constructor that takes more arguments (for dependency injection). Then just make that thing package protected, and put an informal "/** unit test only */" comment there.

What I mean is: there is no such annotation. And it also doesn't make sense to have one. You describe your external interface with clear javadoc, you write your classes so that it becomes **obvious** that a user  should only use/call `fooB()`.

Thing is: the last thing you want to happen is that some test-only artifact in your code causes an issue in your production environment. And the best way to avoid that risk: don't create such artifacts.

Comment: sorry guys didn't understand the joke here :p

Comment: Your answer makes sense. My thinking got caught in an infinite loop. Refactoring logic prod code is the way to go ! :P

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your test package to be the same as as your unit-under-test (UUT).

```
package com.example.fubar.arglebargle;
public class A {
   // package-private, TEST ONLY!
   void fooA() { }

   public void fooB() { }
}
```

Unit test class:

```
package com.example.fubar.arglebargle;
public class TestA {
    // etc...
}
```

My IDE does this automatically with JUnit testing.  All my tests are declared in the same package as my UUT (although they're obviously in a completely different source tree; don't put tests and production source in the same sub-dir!).

This is handy for accessing some internals that wouldn't be available otherwise.  It also seems to be standard practice, so I think there's nothing against doing it.

This won't stop everyone from calling `fooA()`, but it will limit potential problems to classes in the same package as your class.  That's a much smaller set of code to worry about, and often you can rely on people modifying code to read the comments in other classes in the same package carefully.

I think some test frameworks may be able to access private methods (maybe by disabling the security manager?) but I don't know off hand.  If it's important, I'd research test frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Why a code that is used only for tests should be available in production ?

1) it doesn't validate the applicative code as the application doesn't use it.

2)It is error prone for clients of the class that use it.

3)It makes harder the maintainability and the readability of the code. 

For example a developer could wonder why this method is present if it has no caller in the applicative code.
Considering it as dead code, he could remove the method and remove also the unit test that uses it.

To solve your problem, I think that this method that is required in non production environments should be included in the packaging of the application in non production environments but it should be excluded from the packaging in the production environment.
Tools as Maven and Gradle handle very well this requirement.

Actually, you cannot do it as the method makes part of a class that is required in production. So, a first step would be to extract the method for testing purpose in a specific class.
In this way, filtering it would be possible.